# Angular: The best way to prepare new/hidden html page with styles (that only this page needs) for PDF generator

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, pdf

I'm facing a big problem with PDF generation and more specifically with preparing additional html that is not visible for user.

Backend developers prepared service to generate PDF, the endpoint recive html that is string type as param. What I have to do is prepare all html page on 'Generate PDF' button click but is shouldn't be visibible for user even as a preview page. The problems is that is not static page, it contains generic components and wanted html should include styles but only these that are used on preview page (`document.head` takes all application styles).

My idea to handle this task was to create a method with two params: `styles: string, content: string`, that creates full html string. I don't know how to take only needed instead of all of styles, the content I think I just create an alternative view at page with ID, set `visibility: hidden` property and just take it by `document.getElementById('ID').innerHTML`.

Can someone help me with this problem? I can't change the way of generating PDF, it's not up to me :(

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the Dynamic components of Angular if what you need it's to reuse components from your application. With this, you can create all elements in memory, but what you do is to not render the components by calling the `injectComponent` method from the reference, and then you can access the `outerHTML`  property from each native element and fulfill your `content` string. If you don't need to access or reuse Angular elements, I suggest you use simply the native Javascript API to create elements, like `document.createElement('html-tag')`